# Our confusion matrix doesn't make sense

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, transfer-learning, image-classification

We are currently working on an image classification task for detecting tuberculosis from chest x-ray images. You can see our code below. We used 7000 images (3500 each) and divided them using the following fractions: 0.64 for the train set, 0.16 for the validation set, and 0.2 for the test set. Our training and validation loss are also great [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iN4Rx.png). But when we used our model to the test set, the confusion matrix doesn't make sense [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bytma.png). Is there something wrong with our code? Thank you in advance.

```
#Imports
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import MobileNetV2
from keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import preprocess_input
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Model, Sequential
from keras.losses import BinaryCrossentropy
from keras.optimizer_v2.adam import Adam
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report
import numpy as np

#importing the model
image_size = 224
base_model = MobileNetV2(input_shape=(image_size,image_size,3), 
                         weights='imagenet', 
                         include_top=True)

#freezing the base model
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

#adding a softmax layer with 2 outputs
y_layer = base_model.get_layer('global_average_pooling2d').output
z_layer = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(y_layer)
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=z_layer)

#compiling the model
loss_func = BinaryCrossentropy()
opt = Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(loss=loss_func,
              optimizer=opt,  
              metrics=['accuracy'])

#Image augmentation
test_path = '...'
val_path = '...'
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input,  
                             zoom_range=0.2,
                             brightness_range=[0.5,1.5],
                             rotation_range=40,
                             width_shift_range=0.2,
                             height_shift_range=0.2,
                             horizontal_flip=True)

batch_size=32
validation_size=32
train_set = datagen.flow_from_directory(test_path, 
                                        target_size = (image_size, image_size),
                                        batch_size=batch_size,
                                        class_mode = 'categorical')

validation_set = datagen.flow_from_directory(val_path, 
                                             target_size = (image_size, image_size),
                                             batch_size=validation_size,
                                             class_mode = 'categorical')

#Fitting the data into the model
model_history = model.fit(train_set, 
                          validation_data=validation_set,
                          epochs=40,
                          steps_per_epoch=len(train_set)//batch_size,
                          validation_steps=len(validation_set)//validation_size,
                          verbose=1)

#testing the model on unseen data
test_path = '...'
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(test_path,
                                            target_size = (image_size, image_size),
                                            class_mode = 'categorical')

predictions = model_testing.predict(test_set, verbose=1)
y_pred = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
class_labels = list(test_set.class_indices.keys())

print('Classification Report')
clsf = classification_report(test_set.classes, y_pred, target_names=class_labels)
print(clsf)
print('\n')
print('Confusion Matrix')
cfm = confusion_matrix(test_set.classes, y_pred)
print(cfm)
```

Answer (score 0):

first some observations. you have validation_set = datagen.flow_from_directory etc.
The validation data is typically NOT augmented so you should not use the datagen because it creates augmented images. So code should be

```
vgen=ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)
validation_set = vgen.flow_from_directory(val_path, 
                                             target_size = (image_size, image_size),
                                             batch_size=validation_size,
                                             class_mode = 'categorical')
```

I assume the function preprocess_input scales the pixels between the range -1 to +1 as that is what MobileNet was trained on.
Next in your test generator, test_set in flow_from_directory set shuffle=False. Now to get the data for the confusion matrix you have this code

```
predictions = model_testing.predict(test_set, verbose=1)
```

what is model_testing? you compiled your model as model. So it should be

```
predictions = model.predict(test_set, verbose=1)
```

to get the data for the confusion matrix you need to generate an array of the predictions for each test sample and an array of the true labels. Code for that is
shown below

```
labels=test_set.labels
y_pred=[]
predictions = model.predict(test_set, verbose=1)
for i, p in enumerate (predictions):
    index=np.argmax(p)
    y_pred.append(index)
y_true=np.array(labels)
y_pred=np.array(y_pred)
cm=confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
```

OK we have a confusion matrix, now you want to plot it so that it in a way that you can understand the results.

```
length=2 # two classes
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True, vmin=0, fmt='g', cmap='Blues', cbar=False)
classes=list(test_set.class_indices.keys())
plt.xticks(np.arange(length)+.5, classes, rotation= 90)
plt.yticks(np.arange(length)+.5, classes, rotation=0)
plt.xlabel("Predicted")
plt.ylabel("Actual")
plt.title("Confusion Matrix")
plt.show()
```

If you also want a classification report include

```
clr = classification_report(y_true, y_pred, target_names=classes)
print("Classification Report:\n----------------------\n", clr)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I will try your suggestions. The model_testing variable is actually the saved model because we actually used a model checkpoint where the save_best_only is set to True. We then load the saved model and use it to predict on the test set.